# Applying jinja2 filters to a block?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

Is it possible to apply jinja2 filters to `{% block ... %}` constructs?  What I was hoping to do was something along the lines of:

```
{% block content|upper %}
here is some content that will be rendered in upper case
{% endblock %}
```

...but this doesn't work; the above example will result in an error.  Is there any other way to wrap a chunk of template text in a jinja2 filter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [**filter** sections](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#id11):

```
{% block content %}
    {% filter upper %}
        Here is some content that will be rendered in upper case.
    {% endfilter %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I would reverse `block` and `filter`. That way, template extension won't override the filter.

Comment: It depends to particular purpose - nest the `filter` into the `block` to allow overriding or nest the `block` into the `filter` to disallow the overriding. IMHO the first variant is more flexible and the second  variant is good only if you are sure that you'll always need that block to be filtered with defined filters.

Comment: You know, I think I may have stared at that section of the documentation several times today and failed to read it accurately because I was so focused on `{% block ... %}`?  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It's funny, today I found myself wondering, "how do I apply a filter to a Jinja block?", and this was the first Google result. Thanks, past larsks and @EugeneNaydenov.

Comment: @FullyBuzzwordCompliant Appreciate your feedback. It was really funny and pleasant to see that 9 years old Q&A is still helpful to people. :)